# Synchronize RecyclerView with TabLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-tablayout

Can we have TabLayout with Recyclerview below it instead of ViewPager? And, when a tab is selected, the content of the Recyclerview will be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup like this,Add the number of that are needed,at initial data in `RecycleView` for 0 position then add the `addOnTabSelectedListener` and update the list when Tab changed based on it's position

```
 private TabLayout tabLayout;
 private MyAdapter myAdapter;
 private List<MyObject> list;
  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        list=new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter=new MyAdapter(this,list);

        RecyclerView recyclerViewOrderList = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewOrderList);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerViewOrderList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerViewOrderList.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        TabLayout.Tab tab1 = tabLayout.newTab();
        tab1.setText("TAb1");

        TabLayout.Tab tab2 = tabLayout.newTab();
        tab1.setText("TAb1");
        tabLayout.addTab(tab1);
        tabLayout.addTab(tab2);


        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                switch (tab.getPosition()) {

                    case 0:
                        //list 
                        // setup adapter for position 0
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        // setup adapter for position 1
                        break;
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
}
```

Comment: What if I want set tab selected when the corresponding child is visible/at top of the view screen?

Comment: @VikasBorkar you can check the page scroll value to set the tab selected as desired.

Answer (score 2):

I have already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63555216/3810333), but could be still relevant to duplcate it for this question:

It's enough to override RecyclerView's onScrolled and select tab and scroll to position when tab is selected and that Tab wasn't already selected:

```
override fun onScrolled(recyclerView: RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
     val llm = recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager

     // depending on sections'heights one may want to add more logic 
     // on how to determine which section to scroll to
     val firstCompletePos = llm.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition()

     if (firstCompletePos != tabLayout.selectedTabPosition)
         tabLayout.getTabAt(firstCompletePos)?.select()
}
```

Then I have a TextView which is set as customView to tabLayout:

```
tabLayout.addTab(newTab().also { tab ->
         tab.customView = AppCompatTextView(context).apply {
             // set layout params match_parent, so the entire section is clickable
             // set style, gravity, text etc.
             setOnClickListener { 
                tabLayout.selectTab(tab)

                recyclerView.apply {
                    val scrollTo = tabLayout.selectedTabPosition
                    smoothScrollToPosition(scrollTo)
                }
             }
          }
})
```

With this setup you have:

1. Tab selected when user both scrolls and flings
2. RecyclerView is scrolled when user clicks on the tab.

Answer (score 0):

steps-
1.create adapter for recycleview with different viewholders

2.set adapter to fragment class

3.follow the setTabs() method to sync tablayout with recycleview.

public class DetailScreenscrolladapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter
{

```
private static final int ITEM_TYPE_ONE = 0;

private static final int ITEM_TYPE_TWO = 1;

private static final int ITEM_TYPE_THREE = 2;
int itemType;

ArrayList<StoreListModel> arrayList;
Context context;
View view;

public DetailScreenscrolladapter(ArrayList<StoreListModel> arrayList, Context context) {
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.context = context;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());

    if (viewType == 0) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_one, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderOne(view);
    } else if (viewType == 1) {
        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_two, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolderTwo(view);
    }
    view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_three, parent, false);

    return new ViewHolderThree(view);
}

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         itemType= getItemViewType(position);
   
        if (itemType == ITEM_TYPE_ONE) {
            ViewHolderOne viewHolderOne = (ViewHolderOne) holder;
            viewHolderOne.storeName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getStoreName());
            viewHolderOne.Address.setText(arrayList.get(position).getLocation());
            viewHolderOne.storecode.setText(arrayList.get(position).getBa());
            viewHolderOne.assigned.setText(arrayList.get(position).getEnabled());
        } else if (itemType == ITEM_TYPE_TWO) {
            ViewHolderTwo viewHolderTwo = (ViewHolderTwo) holder;
            viewHolderTwo.firstName.setText(arrayList.get(position).getStoreName());
            viewHolderTwo.storecodeok.setText(arrayList.get(position).getLocation());
        }else if(itemType==ITEM_TYPE_THREE)
        {
            ViewHolderThree viewHolderThree=(ViewHolderThree) holder;
            viewHolderThree.shopOwnername.setText(arrayList.get(position).getStoreName());
            viewHolderThree.pno.setText(arrayList.get(position).getBa());
        }
    }
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
     // check based on your requirement
    return  position;
}
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return arrayList.size();
    }

    class ViewHolderOne extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView storeName,storecode,Address,assigned;

        public ViewHolderOne(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            storeName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_storename);
            storecode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_store_code_);
            Address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            assigned = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_assigned);

        }
    }

    class ViewHolderTwo extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        TextView firstName,storecodeok;
        public ViewHolderTwo(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            firstName=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_firstname);
            storecodeok= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_store_code);

        }
    }
class ViewHolderThree extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView shopOwnername,pno;
    public ViewHolderThree(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
      shopOwnername=itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_owneername);
       pno= itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_p_no);

    }
}
}
```

Fragment class code

```
    recyclerView=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_tablayout);
    layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

    DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration = new 
    DividerItemDecoration(getContext(), DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
    setTabs();



  private void setTabs() {
    tabLayout.removeAllTabs();

    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("tab1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("tab2"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("tab3"));



    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            isUserScrolling = false ;
            int position = tab.getPosition();
            if(position==0){
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            }else if(position==1){
               recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(30);
            }else if(position==2){
                recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(60);
            }

              //   else if(position==3){
              //  recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(90);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
```

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener()

{

```
 @Override
 public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState)
```

{

super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

```
     int itemPosition=layoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();

     if(itemPosition==0) { //  item position of uses
          tabLayout.getTabAt(0);

     }else if(itemPosition==1) {//  item position of side effects
       tabLayout.getTabAt(30);

     }
     else if(itemPosition==2){//  item position of how it works
         tabLayout.getTabAt(60);

     }
 }
```

});